# Find button inside fragment from Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Alright so I feel that this question should have been answered somewhere, but all the answers I find cannot solve my problem.

I created a new android `Activity` from eclipse menu, and it added a new Activity which uses a `Fragment` xml layout. In the xml there is one `EditText` and one `Button` and when the button is clicked I want to do somoething with the `String` from the EditText:

```
    Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.syncButton));
    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText e = (EditText)(findViewById(R.id.syncCode));
            Log.d("You entered", e.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

If I place the code in `onCreate()`, I get a `NullpointerException` since the view is not yet created. I have seen solutions using a method `onActivityCreated`, but since I am using an object of class Activity, no such methods exist. Where in the life cycle is it ok for me to put the code, to make sure that the view has been inflated?

Comment: Doesn't getView().findViewById work?

Comment: Or inside **onCreateView** use this  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
        return view;
And use view.findViewById?

Comment: so wait im confused, are you trying to get the string in your fragment or from your fragment in your activity?

Comment: Do you want the answer for using a Fragment, or do you want the Views in your Activity?

Comment: @tyczj In my activity, I set a layout which is a fragment by `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();` (note, it is autogenerated). All my buttons and stuff are in the fragment xml. In my activity I want to access those as variables, so that I can check for clicks, get text etc.

Comment: @NightlyNexus I want to use the Fragment

Comment: Your `Fragment` should handle it's own UI and associated widgets such as `Buttons`. If you need the `Activity` to do something when the `Button` is clicked then you should have a callback method via an interface implemented by the `Activity`.

Comment: Fragments are supposed to be independent, reusable bits to be embedded in one or more activities; from what I understand you are trying to manage the fragment internals from the activity, even though it should be managing itself. Your code should go in the onCreateView method of the fragment, and if necessary it should communicate with the activity the way @Squonk described it.

Comment: Wow, I tried your solutions and it worked, I should have put the code in my Fragment. It seems that the built-in functionality when creating an Activity in eclipse creates fragments even if my design fits better without them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your Fragment:

```
private Button mButton;
private EditText mEditText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sync_button));
    mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sync_code);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "You entered: " + mEditText.getText());
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe responding to events from the containing activity will decrease Fragment reutilization, if possible you should make the fragments as atomic and self-contained as possible, so you can use them in several activities.

Anyway, use the onCreateView event. Something like this:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sms, container, false);

txtBody = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtContrl);
```

Also you could use the `.isAdded` method of your fragment, to make sure is was added to the activity before accessing its children. But again, try to encapsulating the logic inside the fragment, if possible.